# HandsOnTable - Show tooltip for cell

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want to show tooltip for a cell conditionally
For e.g. if the cell value is not valid as per some rules, then show the text of the rule because of which it's invalid.

```
var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example'), {
    cells: function(row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        cellProperties.renderer = 'confirmTradePriceRederer';
        return cellProperties;
    }
});

function confirmTradePriceRederer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.NumericCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    if (value is invalid) {
        td.style.color = 'red';
        //set tooltip here somehow

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working using [comments](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/5.0.1/demo-comments_.html):

[image]

```
var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example'), {
    cells: function(row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        cellProperties.renderer = 'confirmTradePriceRenderer';
        return cellProperties;
    }
});

function confirmTradePriceRederer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
    Handsontable.NumericCell.renderer.apply(this, arguments);
    if (value is invalid) {
        td.style.color = 'red';
        cellProperties.comment = 'Test Comment';

    }
}
```

Comment: Typo in confirmTradePriceRederer, FYI.

Comment: The docs link is dead, also if I adjust to the current version, 0.37.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `td` tooltip like so:

```
td.title = 'tooltip'
```